# How to separate column content in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this mysql table:

```
QA_CONTACT_NAME
'ARAJKONWAR'
'BOONKUAN/CHEECHENG'
'CHEECHENGLAM/KFC'
```

What I want to do is to create another column to separate the one with '/' like this with the left column duplicated:

```
QA_CONTACT_NAME, QA_EMAIL
'ARAJKONWAR', 'ARAJKONWAR'
'BOONKUAN/CHEECHENG','BOONKUAN'
'BOONKUAN/CHEECHENG','CHEECHENG'
'CHEECHENGLAM/KFC','CHEECHENGLAM'
'CHEECHENGLAM/KFC','KFC'
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

mysql query to get the first table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(QA_CONTACT_NAME) FROM table1;
```

Comment: are there always just two names?  or can it be A/B/C or even more?  if so, how many names can there be and what does `select version();` show?

Comment: are you saying you want to add another column to your stored table data? or another column when you select?

Comment: just 2 names. version is 8.0.23

Comment: add another column when i select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce an additional row, you need to join to say if you should be looking at the left or right:

```
select
    QA_CONTACT_NAME,
    substring_index(QA_CONTACT_NAME,'/',if(left_side,1,-1)) QA_EMAIL
from (select 1 left_side union all select 0) left_or_right
join yourtablename on instr(QA_CONTACT_NAME,'/') or left_side
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5ae7dbe8253ec9e2d285eee50c3f9e1)